# How to I give instructions to a Z80 CPU

Tags: z80, 8-bit-microcomputers, homemade

I found a Z80 CPU lying around my house. I've search all over the Internet but I still don't know how do I input stuff and tell it what to do. Help me please

Comment: When you say a Z80 CPU, do you just mean the chip?  Is it on some sort of motherboard?  If so, what?  We need more information to be able to tell if, and how, we can help you.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes i  mean just the chip

Comment: Then I suspect we probably can't help directly - see this similar question http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2070/276

Comment: Same as if you found a Pentium processor laying around.  You need something to use it _with_

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want to build a barebones/simple computer basically from scratch, I'm not sure there's really much you can do with just a CPU chip on its own. Maybe there are some simple tests you can run without having a full computer built up around it, or maybe not, I don't know, but you won't really be able to use it *as a processor* without building most, if not all, of a computer around it. If you just want to see if it works you could find an existing Z80 computer that uses the same package/etc. for the Z80 CPU and swap them out (that would obviously require desoldering the existing Z80 and replacing it with yours, unless it's socketed).